# 3d movement visualizations?

Tags: info-visualisation, 3d

What are effective ways, expected norms and prior art for visually presenting movement in 3d space, or very generalized movement in 3-dimensions x/y/z axis from an accelerometer? I'm beginning to research this and am at a loss as to how to begin. Examples and terms I can research would be helpful. This includes potentially changes from a norm, accumulations of data points, etc as it relates to the recurring 3-d movement (imagine running, or any repeated motion recorded by an accelerometer).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the term "vector visualisation"

Streamlines with colour indicating time seem to be a popular choice. Overlaying glyphs along the line to represent other information may be worth looking into.

http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/vis/lecture_notes/lecture12_2008.pdf